# Unable to start SQL server agent automatically

Tags: sql-server, sql, sql-server-2012

I am working on SQL 2012, I already been set up my SQL server agent in automatic start up mode in windows services as well in SQL config. Even though it was not starting automatically. How can I fix this?

Comment: Are there any hints in the Windows error log? Or the Agent log itself?

Answer (score 2):

What edition of SQL Server are you running?

SQL Server Express does NOT include the Agent. If that's the case, the solution is buying a valid license for a web, standard, developer or enterprise edition - which all include the SQL Server Agent. See the Management Tools section of "[Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx#Mgmt_tools)" for details

Answer (score 0):

Go to run type:

```
services.msc
```

Right click on the SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER)

Try to start it manually if you receive any error please share the screenshot or you can check the logs of Event viewer:

**Windows +R**

Type:

```
eventvwr
```

**Expand to Windows Logs => Application Logs**

Make sure these services are enabled and running:

```
Event Log : Automatic

Performance Logs and Alerts : Manual

Error Reporting Services: Manual

SQL Server : Automatic

SQL Browser: Automatic

SQL Server Agent: Automatic
```